# matlab reading mixed data from file

Tags: matlab

I am pretty new to matlab. I've been reading the documentation but can figure it out why matlab does not correctly read the string from file. What I am trying to do is to read a mixed data type from file. Some sample data is:

```
t a e incl lasc aper meanan truean rupnode rdnnode name
0.000000    1.2712052487 0.8899021688 22.2458  265.2511471042  322.1539251184  -13.6281352271 -130.986 0.155342 0.889756 phaet_000018 
0.000000    1.2712052478 0.8899021575 22.2458  265.2511428392  322.1539270642  -13.6281369694 -130.986 0.155342 0.889756 phaet_000044 
0.000000    1.2712052496 0.8899021868 22.2458  265.2511587897  322.1539149438  -13.6281365049 -130.986 0.155342 0.889755 phaet_000006
```

The first line is header. So here is what I've done so far:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat');
header = fgetl(fid); # I read the header

Now I read the data:

data = fscanf(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s',[11 inf]);
data1 = data';
fclose(fid);
```

I can now access the first element as:

```
data1(1,1)
```

However, when I do:

```
data(1,11)
```

instead of `phaet_000018` I am getting a number (112). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: put a print of the matrix load in matlab

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get that. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First, your [`sizeA`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_sizeA) input to [`fscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html) is backwards. `sizeA` with a vector input is defined as:

> Read at most `m*n` numeric values or character fields. `n` can be `Inf`, but `m` cannot. The output, `A`, is `m`-by-`n`, filled in column order.

So you've asked `fscanf` to give you 11 rows and whatever number of columns. You can't have an `Inf` row specification so you'll want to remove the third input entirely and [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) your data afterwards.

For example:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat');
header = fgetl(fid);

data = fscanf(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s');
fclose(fid); 

% We just happen to know this explicitly, not knowledge to generally assume
ncols = 22;

% Reshape and transpose
data = reshape(data, ncols, []).';
```

Gives us a `3 x 22` `data` array, which is kinda sorta what we want.

---

So where are the extra columns coming from? For `%s` fields, `fscanf` reads the string until it encounters whitespace. Because the output of `fscanf` is a numeric array it must convert this string into a numeric value, so it converts each character to its numeric equivalent (`double(letter)`) and outputs that into the matrix.

Using our above `data` matrix as an example, we have:

```
>> char(data(1, 11:end))

ans =

phaet_000018
```

With this in mind, your initial code only happens to work because all of your strings are the same length. If we change the length of one or more of the strings, this data import will fail:

```
Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 22, not divisible into total number of elements, 65.

Error in testcode (line 11)
data = reshape(data, ncols, []).';
```

---

So what can we do instead? If you *need* this string from your data I would recommend trying `textscan`:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat');
header = fgetl(fid);

data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s');
fclose(fid);
```

This will read your data into a 1x11 [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html), where each column corresponds to a column in your data:

```
>> data{1}  % t

ans =

     0
     0
     0
```

To collect your numeric data you can iterate through the cell array, or you can use the `'CollectOutput'` flag in `textscan`:

```
fid = fopen('data.dat');
header = fgetl(fid);

data = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %s', 'CollectOutput', true);
fclose(fid);
```

Which will output a `1x2` cell array, where `data{1}` is your numeric array and `data{2}` is a cell array containing your strings:

```
>> data{1}  % Numeric data

ans =

         0    1.2712    0.8899   22.2458  265.2511  322.1539  -13.6281 -130.9860    0.1553    0.8898
         0    1.2712    0.8899   22.2458  265.2511  322.1539  -13.6281 -130.9860    0.1553    0.8898
         0    1.2712    0.8899   22.2458  265.2512  322.1539  -13.6281 -130.9860    0.1553    0.8898

>> data{2}  % Strings

ans =

  3×1 cell array

    'phaet_000018'
    'phaet_000044'
    'phaet_000006'
```

Comment: That was an excellent explanation. Thank you for that. 
One final question: If you notice, the first column if a decimal number 0.0000 why does matlab outputs it as 0, although it's been read as %f?

Comment: It just how MATLAB displays it, it's still being stored as a `double`.